# THREE.js spotlight always points at origin

Tags: three.js

I've modeled a simple scene with Clara.io and exported it to THREE.js scene.

1. I have set the castShadow and receiveShadow properties as needed on all my spotlight and meshes in Clara.io's interface. When I load the scene into a simple THREE.js viewer, castShadow and receiveShadow are reverted to false.
2. Spotlight seems to always point at the origin. As a sanity check, changing the spotlight color in Clara.io, exporting, and then reloading in my simple THREE.js sample works.

Screenshots:

http://monosnap.com/image/f1N403Iat86H6MTQJD0Cw7uqy3IYXq

http://monosnap.com/image/vfIe7VlNdH1wWHVqXKPbtmlNaW6aeD

(In the second photo [my app] of course there's no shadow under the chair because the spotlight is pointing the wrong way...)

Simple sample:

https://gist.github.com/fictorial/e7c8addf8bfa4614ee97

Comment: every find an answer for this bud? i'm having the exact same issue

Comment: this is killing me, been looking at the code for hours and the spotlight points to the origin for some reason